# How to do CRUD Update in Entity (.NET 4.0)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I am following this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/739164/Entity-Framework-Tutorial-for-Beginners

and it seems appropriate for our VB.NET 4.0 WinForms app.  But I am confused on the update part.

Basically I can do the create and read part just fine, but not updates.

This is my insert/create code.

```
Private Sub btnInsert_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
    Dim db = New MyEntities
    Dim objEmp As Employee
    objEmp = PopulateEmployeeFromTextboxes() ' this does things like objEmp.Firstname = txtFirstName.text

    db.Employees.AddObject(objEmp)
    db.SaveChanges()
    MessageBox.Show("Insert/Update success!")

End Sub
```

And the read code is this -its a button click and there is a drop down list to select the employee.   And once the employee is selected the textboxes (ie txtFirstName) are updated from data from the database.  So far so good, but I'm not sure how to take an existing record and update it.

```
Private Sub btnSelect_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click
    Dim db = New MyEntities
    Dim empQuery = From emp In db.Employees Select emp

    Dim empList As List(Of Employee) = empQuery.ToList


    cbEmployee.DataSource = empList
    cbEmployee.DisplayMember = "FirstName"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer while digging through the source code, here it is.  Basically on update retrieve an object using LINQ from the database, update the values in the object, and commit the changes.

```
  If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(selEmployee.EmpId)) Then ' UPDATE
        Dim empId As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(selEmployee.EmpId)
        Dim empQuery = From emp In db.Employees
                       Where emp.EmpId = empId
                       Select emp
        objEmp = empQuery.Single()

        objEmp.HREmpId = txtHREmpId.Text
        objEmp.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text
        objEmp.LastName = txtLastName.Text
        objEmp.Address = txtAddress.Text
        objEmp.City = txtCity.Text

    Else

        objEmp = PopulateEmployeeFromTextboxes() ' this does things like objEmp.Firstname = txtFirstName.text
        db.Employees.AddObject(objEmp)
    End If

    db.SaveChanges()
    RefreshData()
    selEmployee = Nothing
```